# Public URL for CiviMail: access denied even for admin

Tags: drupal, civimail, permissions

Drupal 7.67, CiviCRM 5.13.5

Hey everyone,

Trying to view a mailing I've sent through CiviCRM before. I'm logged in with my admin account with all permissions granted.

I've navigated to the specific sent mailing > View Report > Mailing Settings > Public URL. Clicking on that URL gives an "Access Denied" error.

All the mailings I send have "Public Pages" set as the Mailing Visibility (under Publication on the specific mailings). I've also double checked and I do have the "CiviMail: view public CiviMail content" checked for all roles.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: Defintely sounds like a permissions issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds as if you may the ‘Hashed Mailing URL's’ option selected in your CiviMail Component Settings –

Administer > CiviMail > CiviMail Component Settings

/civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/mailing?reset=1

If enabled, a randomized hash key will be used to reference the mailing URL in the mailing.viewUrl token, instead of the mailing ID

Comment: I have the "Hashed Mailing URL's" setting set, but it should still show publicly, just with the hash. Oddly it only effects 1 mailing, the rest are shown in public view just fine with a hash.